# How to get the value from Jsp to servlet without form submit?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have one internal framework which can do refresh on click of check box.

```
<html>
<script>
```

windows.onload()
      js code  to show timer ..
   decrements from 20 t0 1

```
</script>
<body>
<div id="timer"/>(to show the timer)

please check the check box to get a permission:

<input type="check box" id="check" onclick="page refresh(internal framework take care)"/>
(if checked some other fields)

</body>

</html>
```

So on-click of check box page is getting refreshed by internal framework ,

is there anyway i can pass the timer value  to controller(servlet)?.

Sorry i have very less information .

goal is to start the timer where i left while checking the check box.as  I added java script onload of page,the value getting resettled.

Comment: You could do the `ajax` call to send the value to the controller. show us the `page refresh()`

Comment: +1 using ajax is the only way to submit any information to your server without refreshing the whole page. Ajax calls are done using javascript. You can then use a javascript library such as jQuery to make this task simpler & more robust (strong browser support). see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and do a bit of googling to get started with simple example usages